# Node gerando Json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Tenho que desenvolver uma aplicação Java que, por meio de um Json se comunique com o Node e mude o idioma do site.

O problema é: o node tem de acessar as literais/labels do site em `.txt` e transforma-lo em `.json`.

Usando o JSON.parser eu consegui criar um objeto e imprimir a chave-valor que eu especifiquei, mas não consigo torna-lo um `.json`. Alguma ajuda? Segue o código do node:

```
 var sitecadastrar = '{"cadastrartitulo":"Registrierien Company",
"cadastrarnom edaempresa":"Unterhlnem Name",
"cadastrarnomedosegmento":"Segment", "cadastrarbt
nCadastrar":"Registrierien", "cadastrarop0":"Wahl ihre segment...",
"cadastrarop 1":"Raumfahrt und Verteidigung", 
"cadastrarop2":"Landwirtschaft", "cadastrarop3" :"Essen",
"cadastrarop4":"Autos", "cadastrarop5":"Grün Wirtschaft", 
"cadastrarop6":"Maschinen und Anlagen", "cadastrarop7":"Immobilienmarkt",
"cadastrarop8":"Fo rschung und Entwicklung", "cadastrarop9":"Erdöl und
Erdgas", "cadastrarop10":"Ge sundheits und Lebenswissenschaften",
"cadastrarop11":"Finanzdienstleistungen", "
cadastrarop12":"Informationstechnologie", "cadastrarop13":"Bildung",
"cadastraro p14":"Leistung", "cadastrarop15":"Verwaltung",
"cadastrarop16":"Bergbau", "cadas trarop17":"Auslagerung",
"cadastrarop18":"Kleidung/Mode", "cadastrarop19":"Ander e",
"cadastrarph":"Unternehmen Name"}';

 undefined

 console.log(sitecadastrar); 

{"cadastrartitulo":"Registrierien Company",
"cadastrarnomedaempresa":"Unterhlnem  Name",
"cadastrarnomedosegmento":"Segment",
"cadastrarbtnCadastrar":"Registrier ien", "cadastrarop0":"Wahl ihre
segment...", "cadastrarop1":"Raumfahrt und Verte idigung",
"cadastrarop2":"Landwirtschaft", "cadastrarop3":"Essen", "cadastrarop4
":"Autos", "cadastrarop5":"Grün Wirtschaft", "cadastrarop6":"Maschinen
und Anlag en", "cadastrarop7":"Immobilienmarkt",
"cadastrarop8":"Forschung und Entwicklung ", "cadastrarop9":"Erdöl und
Erdgas", "cadastrarop10":"Gesundheits und Lebenswis senschaften",
"cadastrarop11":"Finanzdienstleistungen", "cadastrarop12":"Informa
tionstechnologie", "cadastrarop13":"Bildung",
"cadastrarop14":"Leistung", "cadas trarop15":"Verwaltung",
"cadastrarop16":"Bergbau", "cadastrarop17":"Auslagerung" ,
"cadastrarop18":"Kleidung/Mode", "cadastrarop19":"Andere",
"cadastrarph":"Unte rnehmen Name"}

undefined

var obj = JSON.parse(sitecadastrar); 

undefined

console.log(obj); 

{ cadastrartitulo: 'Registrierien Company',   
 cadastrarnomedaempresa:  'Unterhlnem Name',   cadastrarnomedosegmento:
 'Segment',   cadastrarbtnCadastrar: 'Registrierien',   cadastrarop0:
 'Wahl ihre segment...',   cadastrarop1: 'Raumfahrt und Verteidigung', 
 cadastrarop2: 'Landwirtschaft',   cadastrarop3: 'Essen',  
 cadastrarop4: 'Autos',   cadastrarop5: 'Grün Wirtschaft',  
 cadastrarop6: 'Maschinen und Anlagen',   cadastrarop7:
 'Immobilienmarkt',   cadastrarop8: 'Forschung und Entwicklung',  
 cadastrarop9: 'Erdöl und Erdgas',   cadastrarop10: 'Gesundheits und
 Lebenswissenschaften',   cadastrarop11: 'Finanzdienstleistungen',  
 cadastrarop12: 'Informationstechnologie',   cadastrarop13: 'Bildung', 
 cadastrarop14: 'Leistung',   cadastrarop15: 'Verwaltung',  
 cadastrarop16: 'Bergbau',   cadastrarop17: 'Auslagerung',  
 cadastrarop18: 'Kleidung/Mode',   cadastrarop19: 'Andere',  
 cadastrarph: 'Unternehmen Name' } 

undefined

console.log(obj.cadastrarph); 

Unternehmen Name 

undefined
```

Comment: Gente, na verdade, eu precisava que o node acessasse meu arquivo.txt e gerasse um json com o que tem dentro dele.

Comment: O que são esses `undefined` ao longo da pergunta? qual dos JSON é o que está no ficheiro txt? o ficheiro txt é unico ou há vários?

Answer (score 1):

Para ler um ficheiro de texto e torna-lo um objecto, em NodeJs, tens que usar o [`fs` (fileSystem)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) e o `JSON.parse()`;

```
var fs = require('fs');
var object;

object = JSON.parse(fs.readFile('ficheiro.txt', function(err,data) { return data; }));
```

`object` contém, agora, o json que está dentro do ficheiro.

Answer (score 0):

Instale o npm no node, utilize o módulo FyleSystem (fs) com o comando "npm install" no prompt.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm/tutorial

Após, formate para json com a função "strinffy" e utilize o método "writeFileSync", conforme ex abaixo.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var sitecadastrar ="xxxxxx";

var data = JSON.stringify(sitecadastrar);

fs.writeFileSync('meujason.json',data);
```